# Haskell -> Parse error on 'where'

Tags: haskell

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error?
tar2.hs:40:41: error: parse error on input ‘c’

I've tried to move the where but i get the same error...

The function 'avancar' receives a position and an orientation and gives the new position, according to that same orientation

```
type Caminho = [Passo]
data Passo 
  = Avanca
  | Sobe
  | Desce 
  | CurvaEsq
  | CurvaDir
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

data Mapa = Mapa (Posicao,Orientacao) Tabuleiro
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

type Tabuleiro = [[Peca]]

data Peca = Peca Tipo Altura
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show) 

data Tipo = Rampa Orientacao | Curva Orientacao | Recta | Lava
  deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

type Posicao  = (Int,Int)
type Dimensao = (Int,Int)
type Altura = Int 


    posi :: Tabuleiro -> Posicao -> Orientacao -> Peca
    posi t (x,y) orientacao = (t !! y) !! x 

    tipo :: Peca -> Tipo

tipo (Peca a h) = a


new_pos :: Mapa -> Mapa
new_pos (Mapa ((x,y), orientacao) []) = Mapa ((x,y),orientacao) []
new_pos (Mapa ((x,y), orientacao) (h:t)) | e == Recta = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Norte && orientacao == Norte = Mapa (d, Este) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Norte && orientacao == Oeste = Mapa (c, Sul) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Sul && orientacao == Sul = Mapa (d, Oeste) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Sul && orientacao == Este = Mapa (c, Norte) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Este && orientacao == Este = Mapa (d, Sul) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Este && orientacao == Norte = Mapa (c, Oeste) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Oeste && orientacao == Oeste = Mapa (d, Norte) (h:t)
                                         | e == Curva Oeste && orientacao == Sul = Mapa (c, Este) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Norte && orientacao == Norte = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Sul && orientacao == Norte = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Este && orientacao == Este = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Oeste && orientacao == Este = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Sul && orientacao == Sul = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Norte && orientacao == Sul = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Oeste && orientacao == Oeste = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t)
                                         | e == Rampa Este && orientacao == Oeste = Mapa (b, orientacao) (h:t) 
                                       where 
                                        b = avancar (x,y) orientacao
                                        c = avancar (x,y) (muda_esq orientacao)
                                        d = avancar (x,y) (muda_dir orientacao)
                                        e = tipo (posi (h:t) (x,y) orientacao)

avancar :: Posicao -> Orientacao -> Posicao
avancar (x,y) orientacao = if (orientacao == Norte) then (x,y - 1)
    else if (orientacao == Sul) then (x,y + 1)
        else if (orientacao == Este) then (x + 1,y)
            else (x - 1,y)
```

Comment: The `where` line should be indented as far as the `|` block above. I would suggest starting a newline before the first `|` to avoid that huge block of whitespace.

Comment: @cdk That is not the cause of the problem: guards do not participate in layout. (I tested this in a file myself: having a `where` block indented more than a function definition but less than its guards is perfectly fine.)

Comment: Please copy and paste the source code itself; an image does not allow us to reproduce your error ourselves and test our proposed fixes. Also include enough code that we can load it into ghci ourselves, and test yourself that the code you post gives the error you claim. SO also has some [hints on developing an MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are there votes to close this? This *is* a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @DanielWagner Done it. btw I'm sorry, i'm new to stackOverflow tbh

Comment: @vikingsteve I am the lone close vote; and I wrote a comment detailing my reasoning. The question has changed since then.

Comment: I have voted to close because, as state in the vote, the example does not show the problem, instead having indentation issues with declarations and missing types.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354723/parse-errors-when-using-partial-functions-in-where-statments-haskell/47355251#47355251). It's about white space and tabs relation.

Answer (score 3):

The only parse error I see is that `posi` and the type declaration for `tipo` are indented more than anything else. Once I fix that, this file parses just fine (though there are other errors).